# Why do I get nil objects iterating an array in an ERB template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am new to Ruby and currently trying a few experiments.

I am confused about these scripts:

```
<%=@myworlds[2].topic%>
```

and

```
<% id = 1 %>
<%=@myworlds[id+1].topic%>
```

`@mywodrld` is an instance of a model and `topic` is the field. When executing the first one, the program runs correctly. When I run the second script, I get the following error:

> ```
> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
> The error occurred while evaluating nil.topic
> ```

What causes the nil object?

Comment: I think the problem is that 'id' in the second line of second example is nil.  I don't now Rails, but suppose you can not create a variables in templates this way.

Comment: I still don't get it. I try to debug the second example <%=debug(@myworlds[@id+1])%> like this, and the script runs correctly, but when I runs with adding topic field <%=debug(@myworlds[@id+1].topic)%> it runs fail.

Comment: id cannot be nil, otherwise the code would fall on id+1. @Aditya Hastungkoro Hadi could you check what line <%= "DEBUG: #{id+1}" %> gives you? Maybe it is not 2 as would be expected at first.

Comment: yeah I suspect `id + 1` is actually not 2.  It might be greater than or equal to size of array, so `@myworlds[id+1]` gives back a `nil`

Comment: `@mywodrld` is a typo? I cleaned up the question for readability and to make the title a question.

Comment: Is it possible to turn warnings on for ERB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I try your approach, I can't replicate your problem. It works fine for me. My guess is that you might use the variable id somewhere else also and that when you call @myworlds[id+1].topic  id has some other value. But as I said, only a guess.

However, I recommend that you use another syntax when looping through collections of models in Ruby. Try something like this:

```
<% @myworlds.each do |myworld| %>
  <h1><%= myworld.topic %></h1>
<% end %>
```

And if you really need the value of the iterator, you could always go with:

```
<% @myworlds.each_with_index do|myworld, i| %>
```

Where i keeps track of the current index in the array. Another good thing with this is that id no longer exists in memory after the block ended.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now. I should add a conditions to prevent the not exists index array, just like @anna recomended. Thanks DanneManne, this information is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have no other differences between these two code snippets?

In your comment you say that you have `@myworlds[@id+1]`, in the original question you say `@myworlds[id+1]` (local variable versus instance variable). Can you show the exact code?

Both scripts are OK. You can create variables in one `<% %>` block, and you can use them in another one (if they are in the same .erb file, of course).

The error message says that your array has no element with index `@id+1` or `id+1`. You have to debug the value of the expression used for the index. I guess that there is somewhere some small mistake, like a typo.

What is the output of your `debug(@myworlds[@id+1])` statement when `@myworlds[@id+1].topic` raises the error?

Also try to debug the value of `id`:

```
<pre>The id = <%= debug(id) %> (<%= id.inspect %>)</pre>
```

(Depending on your version of Rails you may want to use `h( id.inspect )`)

Comment: +1 for noticing the `@id` and `id` possible typo. I had to read the line a few time to actually see a difference :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing but for some reason `id+1` is probably not equal to 2.

To check the value of `id+1` you can do that :

```
raise (id+1).inspect
```

Inspect is very useful is you want to see what is in an object :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to solve the problem is. You are trying to each an array data from a model, but u use the parameter `[@id+1]`. No matter the "`id`" is global or local variable, but the problem is in the end of array, there are no array with index "`id+1`". You should add another parameter to prevent the unrecognized parameter.

Try this

```
if((@myworlds.length-1) > @id)
    @id = @id+1
end
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looping over an array, but possibly using a `for` or `while` loop to accomplish it, rather than use an `[].each`. Your sample code doesn't give us enough information to work from so we're shooting in the dark attempting to help you.

Manually creating your index then trying to walk the array tends to run into problems where you either miss the first or last item, or you go too far and get the error you are seeing. Because `each` returns only the items in the array it can't do that.

Something like this might work better:

```
<% @myworlds.each do |world| %>
  ...
  <%= world.topic %>
<% end %>
```

---

I didn't see the answer @DanneManne gave before I wrote my response. I think he's got the right solution.